# Update notification email

Tags: discourse

Currently, I see that discourse sends update notifications to the email address configured as 'contact email' in the settings.

Contact email's purpose is "Email address of key contact responsible for this site. Used for critical notifications such as unhandled flags, as well as on the /about contact form for urgent matters."

The problem is my client wants to get notification of unhandled flags but I, developer, needs to get  emails about available updates for Discourse. I see nowhere to configure my email address to receive only Update notifications. Is there any way to configure this?

Thanks

Comment: wouldn't this question be more suiteable for http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com?

Comment: @pastacool not sure if it's. I see there is already a tag for discourse here and not on superuser. Also this may or maynot involve configuring on the coding level of the discourse app than a settings somewhere in the admin screen.